# Open links from two websites in the same tab

Tags: html

I would like to leverage the ability to control in which tab/window a link opens by the `target` attribute. It works nice, when I have website with multiple links with the same `target` attribute they all open in one tab/window. However if I have links on two separate websites (each on a different subdomain) it doesn't work.

I would like to have a website on eg www.subA.goout.net with a link
`<a href="https://www.google.com" target="my_window">...</a>`
and a website on www.subB.goout.net with eg.
`<a href="https://www.zadnyspe.ch" target="my_window">...</a>`

How would one achieve for these two links to open in the same tab/window? And what exactly are the requirements for the `target` attribute to take an effect?

Comment: You're doing it right. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/8p0ajw4o/)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer _"However if I have links **on** two **separate websites** (each on a different subdomain) it doesn't work."_ - So I don't think this is the same case, maybe some security restrictions but I'm not sure

Comment: Oh, whoops, I didn't get that. I think we can do that with Javascript however (with `window.open`)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Sorry the question isn't very well formulated. However it doesn't work with JS neither. It looks like not only the `target` must be the same, but also page which the link is part of. And that's the most interesting  part of this question. What exactly is needed for two links to open in the same tab?

Comment: Maybe -I couldn't find reliable information about that- this is a security thing :
Imagine if two websites (which don't have anything to do one to the other) opened their external links in the same tab ? That would be a nightmare. And I'm sure you're not the first one asking yourself if it's possible. Actually, if we could, when you get the "confirm your email adress" link in the mail, we'd get it opened in the tab where it says "check your emails".

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer yup exactly. I'm aware of these security implications. However I'm still interested in what exactly the rules are. And if there's any way one could get around this.